# IOS Paypal MPL reinitialization issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I'm using `Paypal's MPL Framework` and all works fine. I have a requirement to change the Paypal application id dynamically (application works with different ids based on user prefs). I'm initializing the Paypal on my main page to follow Paypal documentation.

I was wondering if I can reinitialize paypal if user changed to a different setting?!

I tried calling the `[PayPal initializeWithAppID:appKey forEnvironment:e];` more than once but it seems only first key/call is effective. The calls after the Paypal is initialized i simply ignored.

The only option is to ask user to kill the application and run it again which is annoying at the best.

Help is appreciated as usual.